# Cypress scrolling problem in overflow:auto

Tags: cypress

I am testing a web app which contains a div

```
<div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 429px;" …
```

which contains a large table. I see scrollbars around the table. Now I want Cypress to click on an element in the table. If the element is hidden somewhere down, that's fine. Cypress will automatically scroll there. But if the element is hidden somewhere on the right, Cypress won't scroll to the correct place but complains:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying after 10050ms: `cy.click()` failed because the center of this element is hidden from view: `<input type="radio" …

Why is that? What can I do?

I am using the latest Cypress (13.6.2).

**Edit:** It turns out there were two different problems:

1. for some elements, Cypress did scroll automatically, but not to the correct position.
2. for very few elements, Cypress did not scroll automatically at all.

The first problem happened in wide tables inside "overflow: auto". The second problem happened without any overflow context after I switched the displayBehavior from the default "top" to "center".

Comment: Did you try `scrollIntoView()`? You may need to try on input or cell div depending on the HTML used for the table and which enables `overflow` CSS.

Comment: Yes, I tried `scrollIntoView()`. But it does not change anything, because Cypress scrolls automatically on `click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first it is important to understand, that normally Cypress automatically scrolls e. g. before a `click()`. The default `scrollBehavior` is `"top"`.

It turns out there were two different problems:

1. for some elements, Cypress did scroll automatically, but not to the correct position.
2. for very few elements, Cypress did not scroll automatically at all.

These two problems need different solutions.

1. Setting `scrollBehavior` to `"center"` in cypress.config.ts solved the first problem.
2. For the very few elements, where no implicit scrolling happened at all, it indeed helped to do `.scrollIntoView()` e. g.
   `cy.get("#foo).scrollIntoView().click()` …

Comment: scrollBehavior setting `false` or otherwise has nothing to do with `scrollIntoView()`

Comment: @CristineRose Before `click()` you don't need `scrollIntoView()` because Cypress **scrolls automatically** – unless you set `scrollBehavior` to `false`.

Comment: Why would Cypress add `scrollIntoView()` if you don't need it? If you look at the implementation, it does not use `scrollBehavior`, false or otherwise.

Comment: @K.Osire I don't say that `scrollIntoView()` depends on `scrollBehavior`. I say that `scrollIntoView()` does not matter, because `click()` scrolls anyway. The only exception is that `click()` does not scroll if you tell it not to scroll. Only in that case `scrollIntoView()` has an effect on the outcome of `click()`.

Answer (score 9):

I think Lorraine Toussain is correct. See the example in the docs [scrollIntoView](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollIntoView#Command-Log).

```js
cy.get('#scroll-horizontal button')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
```

The `.should('be.visible')` would be required if there is animation on the scrolling.

Comment: Yes, I tried `scrollIntoView()`. But it does not change anything, because Cypress scrolls automatically on `click()`.

Answer (score 6):

I made a minimal reproducible example from your description, but it does not fail.

**styles** - made the table, the row, and the first column `1000px` to force the second column to be out of view.

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 429px;">
  <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:1000px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="width: 1000px">
        <td id="wide-column" style="width: 1000px">Very wide column</td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Test:**

```js
cy.viewport(500,500)
cy.visit('index.html')

cy.get('input').click()
```

**Result:**

Table is automatically scrolled horizontally.

[image]

If I pin the `cy.visit()` the snapshot shows the table before scrolling occurred.

[image]

Something in your app is preventing the scrolling occurring, or is a fixed-position element that is covering the input regardless of scroll position.

The simplest approach is to disable actionability, if you can't work out what prevents the scroll.

```js
cy.get('input').click({force: true})
```

Comment: Thanks! I admit, `force: true` works. But I think it's rather a workaround than a solution, because e.g. the system may have to wait until the element gets enabled ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scrollTo()` to move the table before clicking.

Something like this (you will have to calculate the distance)

```js
cy.get('table').scrollTo(500, 0, { ensureScrollable: false })
cy.get('table tr:nth-child(3)').find('input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```